# Basic Signal Plotting

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, octave

I have run it for the whole day and the error keeps on happening the prompt says "vector lengths must match" below is my code. What seems to be the problem?

```
fs=8000;
t=0:1/fs:3;
z1=e.^(-t);
figure(1)
subplot(211)
plot(t,z1)
axis([0 3 -1 1])
hold on
z2=sin(10*pi*t);
subplot(211)
plot(t,z2)
axis([0 3 -1 1])
z3=(e.^(-t)).*(sin(10*pi*t));
subplot(212)
plot(t1,z3)
axis([0 3 -1 1])
```

Comment: The error also tells you the line where it happens, it is very important infromation for you, and for us.

Comment: Is this MATLAB or Octave? You've tagged both, but are likely just using one? Please [edit] the question to include your full error message, it should point you to the specific line which is erroneous, and it's pretty clear so have you checked the vector lengths of the variables you're trying to use together?

Comment: For the value e = 2.71828… use *exp(1)* to return the double-precision representation, if you are using matlab, if you are using octave is correct use e.
Also, in `plot(t1, z3)`, t1 is not defined maybe you want to use t instead.
For another questions I suggest you pay attention to @AnderBiguri and @Wolfie comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer rather than a comment because you can't paste images into comments. I just ran your code in Octave exactly as you listed it except for line 15 (penultimate line) where I changed `plot(t1,z3)` to `plot(t,z3)`, as suggested by @josSan, since `t1` is not defined and the formula for `z3` suggests that it is a function of `t`. It spat out the following with no errors:

[image]

It looks like your code is correct, at least if run in Octave. I don't have Matlab so I couldn't try it in that, but as @josSan points out, Matlab doesn't have built-in constants so your use of `e` would give an error, though it would be something like `'e' undefined near line 3` rather than mismatching vector lengths. However, it would probably be more efficient and accurate to use `exp(-t)` instead of `e.^(-t)` whichever application you are using.